# tablesorter sort special characters

Tags: jquery, tablesorter

I use jquery tablesorter 2.0.5b. One of my tablecells conatins e.g. the following data:

`"testtext"`

`testtext2`

The three examples are also shown in the sequence shown above. But I would like to get the following sequence:

`"testtext"`

`testtext2`

What do I have to do for this? Do I have to override a function? Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check out my [fork of tablesorter](http://mottie.github.io/tablesorter/docs/).

One new feature is an option to set where to sort empty cells. You can force it to sort them to the top, bottom or treat their value as zero. Here is [a demo](http://mottie.github.io/tablesorter/docs/example-option-sort-empty.html).

```
$(function() {
  // call the tablesorter plugin
  $("table").tablesorter({
    theme : 'blue',

    // default of emptyTo is "bottom"
    emptyTo: 'top'
  });
});
```